# Energy Data Disaggregation with a regression model/LSTM

Tags: keras, regression, lstm

i am currently trying to develop a model, which takes a timeseries of mains energy data from a household as an input and should disaggregate this mains data in to specific device energy usage which is the target data.

The frquency of the data i use is 10 seconds.

My idea is to use a LSTM sequence to point model which takes a sequence of aggregated mains data as an input and predicts the midpoint of that sequence for a single device/submeter.

Here is the code which creates the dataset as described above:

```
def create_dataset(path_to_dataset:str, device:str, building:int, window:int, start_train:str, end_train:str):

    dataset = DataSet(path_to_dataset)

    input = next(dataset.buildings[building].elec.mains().load())
    target = next(dataset.buildings[building].elec.submeters().select_using_appliances(type=device).load())

    input = input['power']['active']
    target = target['power']['active']

    print(len(input))
    print(len(target))
    # resample
    target = target.resample('1T').mean()
    input_train = input[start_train:end_train].values
    target_train = target[start_train:end_train].values
    input_train = input_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    target_train = target_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    #scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    #input_train = scaler.fit_transform(input_train)
    #target_train = scaler.fit_transform(target_train)

    print(len(input_train))
    print(len(target_train))

    x_train = []
    y_train = []


    for i in range(window,len(input_train)):
        x_train.append(input_train[i-window:i].tolist())
        #y_train.append([np.mean(target_train[i-window:i])])
        y = [target_train[i-window:i]]
        y = y[int(len(y)/2)]
        y_train.append(y)

    input_test = input[end_train:].values
    target_test = target[end_train:].values
    input_test = input_test.reshape(-1, 1)
    target_test = target_test.reshape(-1, 1)
    #input_test = scaler.fit_transform(input_test)
    #target_test = scaler.fit_transform(target_test)

    x_test = []
    y_test = []

    for i in range(window,len(input_test)):
        x_test.append(input_test[i-window:i].tolist())
        #y_test.append([np.mean(target_test[i-window:i])])
        y = [target_train[i-window:i]]
        y = y[int(len(y)/2)]
        y_test.append(y)

    return np.asarray(x_train), np.asarray(y_train), np.asarray(x_test), np.asarray(y_test)

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = create_dataset(r'dataset.h5', 'toaster', 1, 10, '2022-06-04 02:00:00', '2022-08-01 02:00:00')
```

However, i am getting really bad results. I tried different loss functions, activation functions, scaling the data but nothing really improved the predictions. Here is how i build the model:

```
def create_model(x_train, y_train, epochs, window, features):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape = (window, features)))
    model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(64))
    model.add(Dense(1))


    # Compiling the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Early Stopping callbacks
    es_callback = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='accuracy', min_delta=1e-3, patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)

    # Train the model
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, callbacks=[es_callback], validation_split=0.1)

    return model, history
```

For example, i trained the network for the device "toaster" which is turned off most of the time (y_test is 0.0. The predictions dont get that but instead predict values near that.

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions
array([[-0.14068991],
       [-0.12829399],
       [-0.11637664],
       ...,
       [-0.0779351 ],
       [-0.07779408],
       [-0.07804739]], dtype=float32)

y_test
array([[[0.],
        [0.],
        [0.],
        ...,
        [0.],
        [0.],
        [0.]],

       [[0.],
        [0.],
        [0.],
        ...,
        [0.],
        [0.],
```

Am i even using the right model? I think what i am trying to do is a regression and i thought a LSTM would be the right choice for that.

Thanks in advance for your ideas and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The predictions of a model will not be same    .  you need to set your threshold in order to get value . for example you can set error threshold as 0.5 , values more or less by 0.5 will be considered same

Comment: Where is the option to set a threshold? After the prediction?

Comment: Yes you can think of it like a activation function